# Erlang exercise, creating lists

Tags: list, recursion, erlang

I`m learning Erlang and doing exercises from the book:

"Write a function which returns a list of the format [1,2,..,N-1,N].
create(3) -> [1,2,3]."

I have a solution, which is:

```
create(N) ->   create(1, N).
create (M,M) ->  [M];
create(M,N) -> [M | create(M+1, N)].
```

I went through it dozen of times, but I simply can`t understand what is happening on line 2 of the solution. Can please somebody explain? 
Thank you.

EDIT.
Ok, so i think I`m on the right track for understanding it. In line 2, the new list is created where basically 1 will go to the Head and N to the Tail? If yes, then on line 3 M stands for new list that we created on line 2, and N stands for the input integer from the line 1? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 2 of the solution is simply just the base case of a recursive function.

If the two numbers are the same create(3, 3) then it will return a list of [3] back through the recursive function and building a list out of that.

create(3) -> create(1, 3) -> [1 | create(2, 3)] -> [2, | create(3, 3)] -> [3] -> [2 | [3]] -> [1 | [2, 3]] -> [1, 2, 3]

Answer (score 1):

```
create (M,M) ->  [M];
```

That simply means creating a list from M to M, which has only one number, M.

For example,

```
create (1,1)
```

would give you [1], because the list starts at 1 and ends at 1.