# Recursive functions difficult to comprehend

Tags: recursion

I am learning data structure and algorithms. I found it especially difficult to understand recursions. 
So I have the following questions. But they are not related to any specific code.

1. When I implement methods, when/where should I consider recursion?
2. In general coding convention, should I prefer recursion over simple iteration if they are both feasible?
3. How to actually comprehend most possible forms of recursion so I can think of them when I need? What is the best way to learn it? (Any related book or website?) Is there any pattern?

I know the question may sounds unconstructive if you find recursion simple and natural. 
But for me it doesn't align with my intuition well. I do appreciate any help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about CS theory.  Should go to http://cs.stackexchange.com/ or http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @tcaswell The question is most likely too broad for those sites as well.

Comment: I actually like this question, I do however agree that it should go to programming site or cs.

Comment: (2) Generally prefer the one that's the most readable. Every now and again one or the other (usually recursion) will be **way** slower, in which case you should obviously pick the other.

Comment: @LeoCorrea Thanks. Just out of curiosity, what kind of question usually is the right fit for stackoverflow? (like detailed code debugging?)

Comment: Mostly code problems and questions related to actual code. This question for example is too broad.

Comment: @Dukeling: I am not sure on this one. IMHO, if the problem size is predictable and not too big, or if you can ensure tail recursion, your rule applies, but for unpredicable problem sizes and programming languages without tail recursion, this rule could result in catastrophe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1**

Very often recursive solutions to problems are smaller when data can be seen as similar. Eg. If you have a binary tree and you want to get the sum of all the leaf nodes you define `sum-tree` as *If it's a leaf node, it's sum is it's value, if it's not a leaf node it the addition of the sum of both sub-trees.*

Here's a Scheme implementation of my text

```
(define (sum-tree tree)
  (if (leaf? tree)
      (node-value tree)
      (+ (sum-tree (node-left tree))
         (sum-tree (node-right tree)))))
```

Or the same in Java, defined as a method in the Node class.

```
public int sum()
{
    if ( isLeaf() )
        return value;
    else
        return left.sum() + right.sum();
}
```

An iterative solution to this would be longer and harder to read. In this case you should prefer recursion.

**2**

It depends. If you are programming in Python or Java you should not since they donæt have tail recursion. With Scheme however, it's the only way to go. If your language supports tail recursion you should pick recursion when it makes clearer code.

**3**

Learn by doing. You need to write some algorithms that uses recursion as a tool. Use paper to follow the flow of the stack if you are unsure of the flow. Learning some Scheme or a similar functional language might help you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

1. Recursion can be used when you are repeating the same thing over and over. For example, you are traversing a tree, you can use a recursion method to go to the left or right child.
2. I would go for the one that is easier to read. Generally, simple iteration will be faster as it does not have any overhead (recursion has some overhead, and can cause stack overflow if the levels are to deep, while simple iteration won't). But for some case, writing a recursive function is a lot easier than writing the equivalent in the simple iteration.
3. I would rather see the problem first and then decide whether I need recursion to solve it, not vice versa. Any algorithm book should be good enough. Perhaps you can start over reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion to begin with. There is a simple example there about recursion, which I think you will be able to implement too using simple iteration.

Comment: Recursion does not necessarily have overhead, nor does it necessarily lead to potential stack overflows. This is dependent upon the language and compiler, namely whether or not both support tail call optimizations.

Comment: Could you briefly explain why tail call optimizations can stop potential stack overflows caused by recursion? (I read the wikipedia but I still don't understand why it can stop stack overflows.)

Answer (score 1):

At first, wrapping my head around recursion was hard as well. When I was learning recursion it was during school with `Java`. I found it more often I would use recursion over iterators as they were annoying to write in Java. However, I learned `Ruby` and I found myself writing recursive methods less and less. Then, I learned `Elixir` and `Erlang` and found myself writing a lot of recursive functions. My point? Some tools will give themselves for writing with certain style.

Now to answer your questions, since you're just starting to learn recursion, I would suggest diving deep into them and trying to get comfortable with them writing them as much as you can.

Certain tasks are much better off with recursion (e.g. Fibonacci sequence, traversing trees, etc..). Some other's you're better off writing a simple loop. However, note that you can write  any recursive method with a loop. It might get tricky on certain occasions though.

All in all, recursion is actually a pretty cool concept once you get the hang of it.

Take a look at this question that relates to recursion: [Erlang exercise, creating lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949526/erlang-exercise-creating-lists)

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for a study of some well known recursive algorithms. For instance, you could try to implement a factorial computation, or to get all the paths lengths in a tree.

By doing that you'll (hopefully) see how the recursive approach helps to simplify the code, and why it is a good approach in these particular cases. This could give you some ideas for future applications :)